# HTML to JS validation and then Submit to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, http-post

Ask user to enter value in HTML form.
Then validate that form's value with JS if incorrect ask user to make correction.
And if all the JS are executed without any problem then submit that HTML form using PHP

Comment: http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

Comment: You ask your own user. We're here to (maybe) help answer programming questions. This is not a place to dump your to-do list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering a form as folows :

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="monSite/path/to/route">
  //Form fields here
</form>
```

And then the javascript :

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e)
{
  //put your validation logic here
  if(isFormNotValid)
  {
    //display an error and then
    //prevent the form from being sent
    e.preventDefault();
  }    
});
```

i don't understand what you mean by "submit that html form using PHP"

Comment: What i mean is that if the validation is sucessful then it should submit value of that form to a PHP file with post method request.

Comment: Well then, my answer should do it then.
Did you try it ? Did it work ? if so, please select the answer.
Also, you could have found this information on the internet, there are tons of snippets and tutorials allowing to do that.